# how can i use hasMany relationship in kysilk column-sortable package

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

how can i use hasMany relationship in kysilk column-sortable package

```
 public function renterCount()

{

    return $this->hasMany('App\RentalApplication','property_id', 'id');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post but for anyone trying to use the package, you can't use the HasMany relationship. The package author did not implement this type of relationship. Only HasOne, or BelongsTo.